# Two buttons in asp.net C# works weird

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am facing a very weird issue here. I am calling an action (which is a view) and there I have got two buttons. There are separate handles for these buttons in javascript which is placed in the same .cshtml file. The code as mentioned below:

```
@model fbpm.Models.UserDetail

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My View"; }

<style type="text/css">
    #top 
    {
        width:360px;
        float: left;
        height:100px;
        border-left: 1px solid black;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;        
    }
    #right
    {
        width:360px;
        float: left;
        height:100px;
        border-left: 1px solid black;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;             
    } </style>
    <div id="top" class="display-field">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;Name  &nbsp;&nbsp;  : @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserName)    
    <br />
    <br />
    <input id="userid" type="hidden" value = @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserID)></input>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;Address : @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FullAddress) <br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.State) <br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Country)    
     <br /> 
     <br /> 
    </div>
    <div id="top" class="display-field">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;PAN #  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; : @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PANNo)
    <br /><br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;Booked Date&nbsp;&nbsp;: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BookedDate)
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    </div>
    <div id="right" class="display-field">
    &nbsp;&nbsp; Booked Amount&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;: &nbsp; INR &nbsp; @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BookedAmount)
    <br /><br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp; Remaining Amount &nbsp; : &nbsp; INR &nbsp; 
    <label id="ramt"/>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    </div>
    <div id="display" style="clear:both;">
     <button type="button"style="width:150px" id="paysched" name="paysched" onclick="handleflat();">Payment Schedule</button>
     <button type="button" style="width:150px"  id="flat" name="flat" onclick="handleps();"> Flat </button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="container" style="clear:both;"> Click on the above button to display Flat/Payment Schedule </div> <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $.get('@Url.Action("GetRamt", "Customer")?id=' + document.getElementById("userid").value,
        function (amount) {
            document.getElementById("ramt").innerHTML = amount;
        });
        function handleflat() {
            $.get('@Url.Action("GetFlat", "Customer")?id=' + document.getElementById("userid").value,
           function (viewResult) {
               $("#container").html(viewResult);
           });
        }
        function handleps() {
            $.get('@Url.Action("paysched", "Customer")?id=' + document.getElementById("userid").value,
        function (viewResult) {
            $("#container").html(viewResult);
        });
    } </script>
```

However, When I click on the second button (Payment Schedule), its calling the Flat button action. And when i keep clicking the second button, sometimes it works! And when it works, I click on some other area in the window, the first button's function is called.

Please can someone help?

**EDIT: The first button is always highlighted and I guess, thats the problem why the first button's function is always called. I dont want this behavior **

*EDIT2: Meanwhile, i was just playing around with the code and I changed the Button to Radio buttons! Initially, both the radio buttons were not selected and when I click on the second button, the second button is getting selected. Now, is the interesting part => When I click on any part of the result view, the first radio button is getting selected!!! And now, both the radio buttons are ON!!! :(*

**EDIT3: And I named both the radio buttons with the same name. Now, clicking on any part of the result div is making the first radio button selected! **

Placing the mouse over the DIV - CONTAINER, highlights the First button and thats why that button is getting clicked.

Regards,
Hari

Comment: i don't get it. what do you want actually? please be more specific.

Comment: You're using jquery, yet you're doing `document.getElementById` and assigning the events within the html button declarations ?

Comment: I have edited my question. Somehow, the highlight is always ON for the first button and the function is getting called on any action.

Comment: @Dimitar: is that wrong? Please can you suggest an alternate? Is this behavior because of that?

Comment: Can you include the other elements that you'r working with ('userid', 'ramt') ?

Comment: Added the complete code..

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov: Somehow, Whenever I place the mouse over the #Container DIV, it highlights the first button!

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that your html could use some cleaning up for example:

```
<input id="userid" type="hidden" value = @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserID)></input>
```

Becomes:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserID)
```

Also ... `nbsp;` among other things.

And the javascript could be something like this:

```
$(function () {
    // get the user id
    var userId = $('#UserID').val();

    // get 'Remaining Amount' -> this should be included in your view model frankly speaking
    // getting it like this is not "ideal"
    $.get('@Url.Action("GetRamt", "Customer")?id = ' + userId, function (responseData) {
        $('#ramt').text(responseData);
    });

    // bind the button events
    $('#flat').click(function() {
        var flatUrl = '@Url.Action("GetFlat", "Customer")?id = ' + userId;
        getCustomerData(flatUrl);
    });

    $('#paysched').click(function () {
        var paySchedUrl = '@Url.Action("paysched", "Customer")?id = ' + userId;
        getCustomerData(paySchedUrl);
    });

    // handle the response from the server for the customer data
    var getCustomerData = function(url) {
        $.get(url, function(responseData) {
            $('#container').html(responseData);
        });
    };
});
```

I hope this helps.